# Automapper - Filtering data after mapping

Tags: c#, filter, automapper

I have the following code:

```cs
CreateMap<DevicesTransferRequest, TransferRequestDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.SourceCarrierNames, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DeviceMappings.Select(a => a.PreviousCarrier.Name).ToList()))
```

It works, but I want to remove duplicate values for `SourceCarrierNames`.

I try the following:

```cs
CreateMap<DevicesTransferRequest, TransferRequestDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.SourceCarrierNames, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DeviceMappings.Select(a => a.PreviousCarrier.Name).ToList()))
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => dest.SourceCarrierNames.Distinct())
    ;
```

but I see duplicate `SourceCarrierNames` inside every `TransferRequestDto` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Enumerable.Distinct Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.distinct?view=net-6.0)

Returns: `IEnumerable<TSource>`

An IEnumerable that contains distinct elements from the source sequence.

---

Assign the result after distinct back to `dest.SourceCarrierNames`.

```cs
CreateMap<DevicesTransferRequest, TransferRequestDto>()
    .ForMember(d => d.SourceCarrierNames, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.DeviceMappings.Select(a => a.PreviousCarrier.Name).ToList()))
    .AfterMap((src, dest) => 
    {
        dest.SourceCarrierNames = dest.SourceCarrierNames
            .Distinct()
            .ToList();
    });
```

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Add `.ToList()` in the end.